# How to import samples to iElectribe

Tags: ios, applications, third-party

As far as I can tell from some youtube videos, it is possible to use different drum samples in iElectribe by KORG, but I can't figure out how or find any documentation on this.  Does someone know how this is done?

Comment: Everything I've seen says you cannot import your own samples in to iELECTRIBE. Even [Korg's own documentation](http://www.korguser.net/ielectribe/en/follow.html) makes no mention importing samples (but it does talk about exporting samples).